# Find number in string and return location and length

Tags: swift, numbers, find, return, location

```
let myStr = "I have 4.34 apples."
```

I need the location range and the length, because I'm using NSRange(location:, length:) to bold the number 4.34

```
extension String{
    func findNumbersAndBoldThem()->NSAttributedString{
         //the code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is also based on regular expression but there is a more convenient way to get `NSRange` from `Range<String.Index>`

```
let myStr = "I have 4.34 apples."
if let range = myStr.range(of: "\\d+\\.\\d+", options: .regularExpression) {
    let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: myStr)
    print(nsRange)
}
```

If you want to detect integer and floating point values use the pattern

```
"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"
```

The parentheses and the trailing question mark indicate that the decimal point and the fractional digits are optional.

Comment: if my apples are 4 the range is nil.. how to fix it ?

Comment: Thank you Sir! Can you please tell me where I can read about this ->. "\\d+(\\.\\d+)?" expressions to understand it ? Thanks!

Comment: A good tutorial is [Ray Wenderlich: NSRegularExpression Tutorial and Cheat Sheet](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2725-nsregularexpression-tutorial-and-cheat-sheet)